# C# Rdlc Unable to Display Subreport Limitation Issue

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportingservices-2005

Is there a limit to the number of charts I can display in a report using SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 (SSRS 2005) in C# running on VS 2008?

I am unable to display more than 71 charts, for anything greater than that it displays an error message on the report: Error: Subreport could not be shown. The charts are generated as part of a subreport at run time from a template rdlc file (representing one chart). When I replaced the template with a 72 graph rdlc file, this produced a compile error:  Error 72 The value of the Top property for the rectangle ‘Rectangl72’ is “408.75cm”, which is out of range.  It must be between 0mm and 4064mm.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. It is more likely that you have issue with that particular chart.

Comment: At run time a number of identical charts are generated from the template rdlc file (e.g. 2 copies of the chart within the template rdlc file will be made when generating 3 charts). I am able to display 71 charts but not 72. I would have thought that I would be unable to display the chart at all if there was an issue with this chart. The template rdlc file contains a rectangle consisting of 9 controls (1 chart and 8 text boxes). For example, for 72 graphs this will be generating 648 controls. Could there be a limitation with the number of controls?